# Instalé Anaconda pero no viene con VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, anaconda

Instalé Anaconda pero no incluye Visual Studio Code en sus aplicaciones.
Me pregunto si se tiene que hacer algo más, instalé mal VS Code o no hay algún problema.

Es decir, ¿tengo que tener VS Code en la lista de apps de Anaconda para que funciones o no?

Muchas gracias <3

Comment: Tu pregunta puede terminar cerrada, pues **no cumple los estándares de calidad**, tal y como dice en [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): **Busca e investiga** antes de preguntar, puede que en internet encuentres una solución ejemplar para tu problema, este sitio fue pensado para resolver problemas en un código en específico

Comment: VSCode es un IDE, integrated development environment, no tiene nada que ver con Anaconda. Debes instalar VSCode por tu cuenta, ya que te va a servir para programar, o puedes usar un editor de texto cualquiera como notepad o notepad++.